# Redirect all traffic from one domain to another

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I am trying to do is automatically redirect the domain for one of my sites

`www.domain1.com` to `www.domain2.co.uk`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.com\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%www.domain2.com\%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]
```

I have looked over the site for the answer and the above is my code that I edited from another answer, but it doesn't work.

I would like it in a .htaccess file - is this the best way of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: are both domain hosted on same server (same cPanel for example)? or domain1.com is hosted on another server?

Answer (score 22):

To redirect from `www.domain1.com` to `www.domain2.co.uk`, you may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.co.uk/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: I corrected the destination domain in the rule per the original post.

Comment: @David Thanks a lot. I was looking at the rewrite rule `domain2.com\` but I agree it should be the one in the question.

Comment: From an SEO standpoint, is it a bad idea to do something like this or will it not have an effect?